# Why doesn't my loop echo for all iterations?

Tags: php, loops, do-while, tag-cloud

I'm trying to make a tag cloud system getting its values from PHP/SQL but it seems to work erratically, only giving a handful of the expected results. What's causing this odd behaviour?

As far as I can tell it should loop through a total of 20 times (0-19) and each time it adds a string into an array.

The system starts out by getting the 20 most popular tags from my database in descending order, once its got this I create a string and set the font size. This string is then stored in an array and is echoed out using a random number array giving a random order to the cloud.

I then increase the value of i for my loop iteration whilst decreasing the font size for the next less popular tag.

```
<h1>Tag Cloud</h1>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY count DESC";
        $tags_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);           
        $i = 0;
        $tag_array = array();
        $tag_size_max = 36;
        $tag_size_min = 16;

        $numbers = range(0, 19);
        shuffle($numbers);

        do {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tags_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $tag = $row["tag"];  
            $tag_count = $row["count"];             


            $tag_array[] = "<p style='font-size:".$tag_size_max."px; padding:0px;'>".$tag."</p>";

            echo $tag_array[$numbers[$i]];

            $i++;
            $tag_size_max--;    

        } while ($i < 20);
    ?>
```

You can see it kind of working in the footer of my site http://www.vwrx-project.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to echo $tag_array element with index which isn't yet in the array itself.
You would probably need two loops - first to fill the $tag_array, and another one to echo them.

Do you have proper ERROR_LEVEL - there should be some notices about missing indexes - at least if I'm ready your code correctly ;)

Something like this:

```
// fill the array
for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tags_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $tag = $row["tag"];  
    $tag_count = $row["count"]; // this seems to be unused
    $tag_array[] = "<p style='font-size:".$tag_size_max."px; padding:0px;'>".$tag."</p>";
}

// echo the array
for ($i=0; $i<count($tag_array); $i++) {
    echo $tag_array[$numbers[$i]]; 
}
```

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages with it atm so I assume not, I'll add some in and see what it says, ok having just added error reporting in I get "Undefined offset" which I would have googled to find out what it meant.

I believe your right about using two loops so will try it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem occurs in the following line

```
echo $tag_array[$numbers[$i]];
```

when you push to the array

```
  $tag_array[] = "<p style='font-size:".$tag_size_max."px; padding:0px;'>".$tag."</p>";
```

you get an index for each tag , for example

```
[0] =>"<p style='font-size:".$tag_size_max."px; padding:0px;'>".$tag."</p>";     
[1] =>"<p style='font-size:".$tag_size_max."px; padding:0px;'>".$tag."</p>";
```

for every iteration

and then in the following line you echo a random element (probably different form the one you just created )from the array by using the $number array which is not ordered after shuffling it.

I suggest you shuffle the results from the database first with

```
   $results = array();
  while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($tags_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
    array_push($results, $row);
  }

  shuffle($results);
```

and then create a "normal" loop for printing in the tags using the results array.
Also if you need only 20 tags why not adding LIMIT 20 to your query to simplify the code?

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't want to limit directly from the sql at the moment as I'm still experimenting with the system, I'm hoping to maybe allow a setting where users can choose how many tags they wish to see

Comment: In this case you can pass the number of tags as a parameter in your query